# kebab-case в компонентах MDB для Vue

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vue3, code-style, mdb

В документации Vue ([вот тут](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/component-registration.html#%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) указано , что для подключения компонентов в DOM нужно использовать kebab-case...

я использую [Material Design for Bootstrap 5 & Vue 3](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/) и там компоненты прописаны через PascaleCase (хотя для Bootstrap 4 используется kebab-case).

Вопрос: нужно ли, основываясь на документации Vue, подключать компоненты используя kebab-case:

```
components: {
  ...
  "mdb-tab": MDBTab,
  ...
},
```

или оставить как есть, что будет странно так-как свои компоненты я подключаю через kebab-case:

```
...
<my-first-component />
<MDBTab></MDBTab>
<my-last-component />
...
```

Comment: ```<MDBTab></MDBTab>``` - так будет неправильно. Во-первых для DOM регистр не важен и они будут приведены к ```<mdbtab></mdbtab>```. Во-вторых, DOM элементы из одного слова зарезервированы для стандартных элементов (нет гарантии, что не появится стандартный элемент <mdbtab>, но есть гарантия, что не появится cтандартный элемент <mdb-tab>)

Comment: "<MDBTab></MDBTab> - так будет неправильно..." - <MDBTab></MDBTab> - это взято с доки mdb